# Dynamic plugins in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

The question is how one can achieve similar ***"thing"*** in Angular 2+ to that I managed to do in AngularJS. What the ***"thing"*** is I will describe below.

### Question description

So the process that I created in AngularJS can be described as follows:

- We want to inject a custom dynamic content into a page, let's call it a plugin
- That content **is not defined** in the web-client, instead it is being retrieved from a server in a structured form

That is we receive from the server **html** and **js** files that are necessary for the plugin to function and we load and display on the page. On the client I create an AngularJs directive to hold the necessary logic if the plugin.

Here is the code example for javascript  plugin code:

```
() => {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'directive-template-name',
        restrict: "E",
        controller: ['$scope', ... /* other dependecies */, function ($scope, ...) {
            /* directive code */
        }]
    };
}
```

Here is the code example for plugin loader code:

```
// evaluate js function and compile directive
var diretiveFactory = eval(content.jsFile);

// AngularJS CompileProvider
CompileProvider.directive.apply(null, [content.name, diretiveFactory]);

// append html code to element using angular
var wrapper = angular.element("#" + wrapperName);
wrapper.html(requestedDirective[0].htmlContent);

// initialize dynamic content
var wrapperScope = wrapper.scope();
this.$compile(wrapper)(wrapperScope);
```

As one can see, this method allows to load a valid javascript and *"compile"* it into a AngularJS directive and then display it on the page at will.

### Angular 2+

The problem with new angular is that concept of the **directive**, as far as I understand, is replace by a concept of **component**. Moreover, all client-side code is now written in typescript and transpiled into javascript for the client's browser. As far as I understand, all dependencies are being resolved in the traspilation process.

**That creates some problems** that prevent from creating dynamic plugins for Angular 2+:

- A do not know how to inject dependencies into a dynamically created component as I do not know what exactly do I need when the transpilation happens.
- Let's say I want several components to co-exist simultaneously (for example a parent dynamic components that holds children componets) and be able to communicate, in the case of AngularJs I could solve this problem by using scope variable. In case of Angular 2+ components are isolated so how to I go about this problem.
- Moreover, I do not know how one can go about creating *ViewContainerRef* to hold the dynamically created component in evaluated javascript code. (See code examples below)

I will provide code examples of I got so far below. Content loader typescript code:

```
//some imports
import { Component, ComponentRef, Compiler, Injector, NgModule, NgModuleRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

// plugin content structure
class DynamicPageModel {
    name: string;
    htmlFile: string;
    jsFile: string;
}

export class DynamicContentService {

    constructor(
        private _compiler: Compiler,
        private _injector: Injector,
        private _m: NgModuleRef<any>
    ) { }

    public LoadDynamicContent(container: ViewContainerRef, content: DynamicPageModel) {
        // evaluate js function and compile component
        var tmpCmp = Component({
            template: content.htmlFile,
            selector: content.name
        })(eval(content.jsFile)());
        var tmpModule = NgModule({declarations: [tmpCmp as any]})(class { });
        var factories = this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(tmpModule)
        var f = factories.componentFactories[0];

        var cmpRef =  f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);

        // insert component into the container
        container.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
    }
}
```

For reference to what is going on in this piece of code, I got it from [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e).

Plugin example javascript code:

```
() => {
    function dynamicMain() {
        this.componentName = 'Dynamic Example Main';
    }
    return dynamicExampleMain;
}
```

As one can see, this is quite simple dynamic plugin that is unable to use any services or other components as it is unable to inject them into itself.

### Expected answer

As an answer to my question I would like to hear a solution(s) to the problems I encountered when trying to create dynamic plugins for the Angular 2+.

If you know a better approach to creating dynamic plugins (remember: they are retrieved from a server) at run time in Angular 2+, I would like to hear it too.

Comment: Have you tried these: 
1) https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader 
2) https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: You see, I cannot write plugins in the typescript as a trasnpilation process is over **before** the loading of dynamic plugin. Moreover I cannot define plugin code in the Angular client application. It is retrieved from a server separately.

Comment: @Konstantin I have been doing research on the topic as well and I found an interesting solution in this blog: https://itnext.io/how-to-build-a-plugin-extensible-application-architecture-in-angular5-736890278f3f. You can also check out the github repository with the example - https://github.com/ionepaul/angular-plugin-architecture.